# How to get the serial number of the record after executing a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How do I get to know a particular user's rank, after the query is executed? This is in SQL Server 2005. For example, the query that I use is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getmyRankinContest]
@UserID int 
AS
BEGIN

   select userid,
   from
   invitecount
   group by userid
   order by sum(points) desc
END
```

But `@UserID` is my `UserID`. How can I add `@UserID` in the above code to get my rank? Any suggestions, please?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getmyRankinContest] @UserID int 
AS
BEGIN
    ;WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT userId, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Points DESC) Ranking
        FROM (  SELECT userid, SUM(points) Points
                FROM invitecount
                GROUP BY userid) A
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE UserId = @UserID
END
```

Comment: +1 I converted your answer to a [Data.SE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1593)

Comment: That's very useful, thanks.....now I know what my ranking is (though I'd rather not say)